# ASP.NET Multiview Step, Catching the user hitting back button in browser on final step

Tags: asp.net, multiview

I build a multiview form which has 3 steps.

On the last step I simply show a confirmation screen and set this variable.

```
            //Set Session Variable to remember registration is completed
        Session["CodeProcessed"] = "CodeProcessed";
```

After I perform my insert into the database.

Then in my pageload I have

```
if (Session["CodeProcessed"] == "CodeProcessed")
    {
        Session["CodeProcessed"] = "";
        MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
        Response.Redirect("register.aspx");
    }
```

Sending the user back to start. So for example if they get to step 3 and click refresh on the confirmation screen they go back to start which is fine. But if the user gets to step 3 and clicks back in the browser button that page loads fine and step 2 loads again. How could I stop it from doing this and redirect back step 1 ?

Comment: are you using AJAX to change your Views? or a postback to change steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `History` control in asp.net to make sure Back button leads to the View you wish user to be taken to

```
protected void MultiView1_ActiveViewChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    History1.AddHistoryPoint("currentPage", ((MultiView)sender).ActiveViewIndex);
}
```